# Sodium fails to install when on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When trying to install Sodium with NPM on my Raspberry Pi, the installation always fails and complains that it does not have write access to `/home/Captain/node_modules/libsodium`. I'm running the installation command through `sudo`, and the install still doesn't want to work. Did I just royally mess up my install?

```
$ sudo npm install sodium

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/Captain/node_modules/libsodium
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/Captain/package.json'
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of erlpack@hammerandchisel/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.2.1 requires a peer of uws@^0.14.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Captain No description
npm WARN Captain No repository field.
npm WARN Captain No README data
npm WARN Captain No license field.

npm ERR! path /home/Captain/node_modules/libsodium
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -40
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/home/Captain/node_modules/libsodium'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-21T02_23_41_242Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

no, your setup is fine.

try this command

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/Captain/node_modules/libsodium
```

that should fix it.

EDIT: I know this is a 2 year old answer but I would like to tell people who stumble across this post to **NEVER** use 777! 777 allows **anyone** to read, write and execute your file, you **SHOULD** use 644 which allows anyone to read the file only while you can read and write said file.